Hilt DI conflicts with newest versions of Android Gradle Plugin
In my android app I use latest (2.52) version of hilt
[versions]
hilt = "2.52"
[libraries]
hilt-android = { group = "com.google.dagger", name = "hilt-android", version.ref = "hilt" }
hilt-android-compiler = { group = "com.google.dagger", name = "hilt-android-compiler", version.ref = "hilt" }

Also I use old version of Android Gradle Plugin (agp)
[versions]
agp = "8.2.2"
[plugins]
android-application = { id = "com.android.application", version.ref = "agp" }
android-library = { id = "com.android.library", version.ref = "agp" }

gradle-wrapper.properties:
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.7-bin.zip

This setup works fine. I can build my release bundles and publish it without problems.
But time is flowing, and I need to update my AGP to avoid problems in future, when new technologies will require latest AGP. So, I updated AGP to 8.7.2, as my IDE suggested:

Now my versions looks like these:
[versions]
agp = "8.7.2"

distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.9-bin.zip

After this I still can run my apps in DEBUG mode, but when I try to build release version, I get error from Hilt:
error: ComponentProcessingStep was unable to process 'com.ilyin.projectfillword.GooglePlayApplication_HiltComponents.SingletonC' because 'com.ilyin.billing.showcase.ShowCase' could not be resolved.
  
  Dependency trace:
      => element (CLASS): com.ilyin.core.di.GameBillingModule
      => element (METHOD): provideFillwordShowcase(com.ilyin.billing.showcase.ShowCase,android.telephony.TelephonyManager)
      => type (EXECUTABLE method): (com.ilyin.billing.showcase.ShowCase,android.telephony.TelephonyManager)com.ilyin.core.feature.billing.showcase.FillwordShowcase
      => type (ERROR parameter type): com.ilyin.billing.showcase.ShowCase
  
  If type 'com.ilyin.billing.showcase.ShowCase' is a generated type, check above for compilation errors that may have prevented the type from being generated. Otherwise, ensure that type 'com.ilyin.billing.showcase.ShowCase' is on your classpath.

I'm pretty sure that ShowCase isn't generated type. Also, it imported successfully and available.
Here what GameBillingModule looks like:
package com.ilyin.core.di

import android.telephony.TelephonyManager
import com.ilyin.billing.showcase.ShowCase
import com.ilyin.core.feature.billing.showcase.FillwordShowcase
import com.ilyin.core.feature.billing.showcase.FillwordShowcaseImpl
import dagger.Module
import dagger.Provides
import dagger.hilt.InstallIn
import dagger.hilt.components.SingletonComponent
import javax.inject.Singleton

@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
class GameBillingModule {

  @Singleton
  @Provides
  fun provideFillwordShowcase(
    generalShowCase: ShowCase,
    telephonyManager: TelephonyManager,
  ): FillwordShowcase {
    return FillwordShowcaseImpl(
      generalShowCase = generalShowCase,
      telephonyManager = telephonyManager,
    )
  }
}

GameBillingModule located in core module, and ShowCase in the billing module. Here how I included billing to core:
implementation(project(":billing"))

Why does Hilt show me errors after I updated AGP? How to solve it?

Does this answer your question?

@JanItor setting isMinifyEnabled = false allows me to build release bundle, but twice with it's size (11 Mb -> 22 Mb). Also, minifying is very important to make app more quick and smooth. The cost of your solution is too high, I can't accept it.

In which modules isMinifyEnabled is set to false and in which to true?

@JanItor I disabled it in all modules. I'm pretty sure, disabling isMinifyEnabled in any module for release is a very bad idea due to resasons I described above. Need another solution

Does it build if you only disable it in billing and keep in the main module?

Library can be minified later, together with the main module. That's what consumerProguardFiles is for - to provide proguard rules for later minimization.

@JanItor I set isMinifyEnabled to false in all lbirary modules and true in all app-modules. It allowed my to upgrad AGP to the latest version and build my releases. Bundle's size increased by 30%, but size of the downloadable file slightly reduced, when I released it. So, your solution works fine and I implemented it for production.
